# How to use beautiful soup to create user events?

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

can beautiful soup be used to create user events such as adding search string in the search box, clicking a button, selecting an option from the list, clicking an item etc?

Comment: bs works with static files. it can modify them, but it can't "interact" with them - just like a text editor which can only display&modify the website's source code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, `BeautifulSoup` is an **HTML parser**, it's great at what it does, but it is just an HTML parser.

It can potentially assist you in extracting information needed for making HTTP requests to simulate requests that a browser would send, but then, to make an HTTP request, you would use another library - [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) is the most popular one. There are libraries that try to combine the two - [`mechanicalsoup`](https://github.com/MechanicalSoup/MechanicalSoup) or [`robobrowser`](https://github.com/jmcarp/robobrowser).

Overall though, it feels like you are asking about doing *browser automation* - for that [`selenium`](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) would fit your requirements in the most direct manner.

Check out a relatively fresh [`requests-html`](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests-html) package as well which was introduced as a yet another "for humans" library a few months ago with no changes after. Still, worth exploring.